# MongoDB extend Embedded Documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document as follows:

```
{
  _id: ... ,
  field_1: ...,
  field_2: ...,
  changes:{
    "1474607149339":"a7hhs",
    "1474607149463":"98nhs",
    "1474607149657":"cxskk9",
    "1474607149880":"csdda3",
    "1474607151575":"bfddrd",
    "1474607153389":"54fbbb",
  }
}
```

The big numbers in the `changes` are timestamp values. (this is to track history of certain fields in my application). 
I'm sending this changes as small chunks containing few similar entries 
eg:

```
{
        "1474607159708":"zcdgv",
        "1474607159932":"4h7kk",
        "1474607165362":"nbmnn"
}
```

how can I extend the `changes` field in the mongo document to include new changes in a single query (large number of changes need to be recoreded)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to insert fields into existing documents using the `$set` operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set: { 
              "changes.1474607159708": "zcdgv",
              "changes.1474607159932": "4h7kk",
              ....
           } 
   }
)
```